# Wpf change rectangle color depending on selected value of listbox using ivalueconverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, ivalueconverter

I need to change a rectangle color(fill) depending on the selectedvalue of a listbox using ivalue converter. this is my code

xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <cc:ConversorEstados x:Key="ConverterEstados"/>

</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="tipo_estado" Source="/Resources/Estados.xml" XPath="/estados"/>

    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="Lista"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource tipo_estado},
XPath=tipo/@name}" DisplayMemberPath="Opcion" Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="199" />
        <Rectangle Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="304,45,0,0" Name="rectangulo" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="221" 
Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ConverterEstados}}" />

    </Grid>
```

This is my converter class

```
 public class ConversorEstados : IValueConverter
{


    public string Opcion { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (value.ToString().ToLower())
        {
            case "opcion1":
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
            case "opcion2":
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
            case "opcion3":
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
            case "opcion4":
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);
            default:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

bus it is not working. it shows no error when execute but when i change my selection in the listbox nothing happens, it takes the default value - white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind to the `ListBox` directly. Try this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Lista"/>
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=Lista, Converter={StaticResource ConverterEstados}}"/>
```

We just added `SelectedValue, ElementName=Lista` to the binding of the fill.

**EDIT 1**

Also, your converter needs to check for null values because the `ListBox` will start with an unselected state. Add this to your `Convert` method:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    switch (value.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "opcion1":
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
        case "opcion2":
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
        case "opcion3":
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
        case "opcion4":
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);
        default:
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: i try and it marks an error in the line - switch (value.ToString().ToLower()) (Null referenceException)

Comment: ok i add an if  to control null value and now it works, but the text in the listbox disappear but it work, the listbox seems empty but when i click in every item (blank space) it chage the color. now Why the text in listbox disappear? could it be for the change Name to x:Name?

Comment: ah it was my mistake when i delete property displayMemeberPath it shows the list. now it works perfect. thanks man!!

Comment: Added a fix to your null exception.